# Reported speech within conditionals - to backshift or not?

Tags: grammar, tense, reported-speech, conditionals, tense-agreement

I might be very wrong in what I'm about to ask, so sorry in advance.
Imagine someone says to you:

> I like cats.

Now you want to report what they said to some other guy/gal but with an added twist - you want to make it a conditional.

> If you ask her, she'll tell you that she likes cats.

No backshifting needed - sounds okay, right? If I decided to make it a second conditional now, I'd say:

> If you were to ask her, she'd tell you that she likes cats.

**Question** #1. Does it make sense to backshift here - no, right? I feel like it's still discussing something that's true in the present and the verb I should look at to choose whether to backshift or not is the reported speech verb 'tell' which is in the present, no?

Fast forward five years into the future. She doesn't like cats anymore - she likes dogs.

> If you had asked her five years ago, she would've said that she liked
> cats.

**Question** #2. I do need to backshift here, right? Because it's a past fact that's no longer true, no?

Then if I have a slightly different scenario where the original sentence is in the simple past - how do I change it? Imagine someone says to you:

> I didn't do it!

**Question** #3. How would the three conditionals look like in this case? Which one's do I have to backshift?

> I: If you ask him, he'll say that he didn't do it.
>
> II: If you asked him, he'd say that he didn't do it.
>
> III: If you had asked him, he would've said that he hadn't done it. *(This sound weird, no?)*

Am I doing it correctly? All of what's above is a guess - so if someone could explain to me where I'm right (if anywhere) and where I'm wrong, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Hello august99, FYI, two things we don't do on this site are proofreading ("Is my sentence correct?") and multiple questions in one, so this question may get closed. FWIW, every one of your sentences is correct and natural, even the last one.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I didn't want this to be a proofreading exercise - I just didn't know how to explain best what I am confused about so I had to use a lot of examples. But thanks. Sorry again